# Event not firing

Tags: solidity, truffle, events

I've seen other similar questions but I can't seem to pinpoint the error

In my contract

```
contract Authentication is Killable {

  event FriendEvent (bytes32 name, bytes32 handle);

   function login() constant
   public
   onlyExistingUser
   returns (bytes32 n, bytes32 h) {
      FriendEvent(users[msg.sender].name, users[msg.sender].handle);
      return ("wtf", users[msg.sender].handle);
   }
}
```

and then I'm calling the event in my code

```
 var authenticationInstance

 // Get current ethereum wallet.
 web3.eth.getCoinbase((error, coinbase) => {
    // Log errors, if any.
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    authentication.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      authenticationInstance = instance


      var exampleEvent = authenticationInstance.FriendEvent({_from: web3.eth.coinbase}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});

      //Call Watch on event
      exampleEvent.watch(function(err, result) {
        console.log("----------EXAMPLE EVENT");
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return;
        }
        console.log(result.args._value)

      })


      // Attempt to login user - calling the login function
      authenticationInstance.login({from: coinbase})
      .then(function(result) {
      ....
```

The login function executes fine, but "----------EXAMPLE EVENT" isn't printing to console. I've also added fromBlock, toBlock like suggested in another post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is marked `constant` which means it can't alter the contract state on the chain, which means the event is never written to the chain, which means the event will never arrive.

Remove `constant` (and don't use `.call()` on the JS side). The client will receive a transaction receipt for the submitted transaction.

Wait the event to arrive.

Hope it helps.

Comment: omg thanks lifesaver <3 spent lots of time on this issue D: